# "Including the likes of A, B, C" vs. simply "including A, B, C"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I found the following sentence in [a sports report](http://www.goal.com/en-gb/news/2896/premier-league/2014/11/01/5682481/van-gaal-im-not-jealous-of-manchester-city-squad?ICID=HP_BN_1?CMPID=FBUK_%3C141101%3E%20_%3Cvangaalnotjealous%3E):

> Manuel Pellegrini's men claimed their second title in three years last season and boast a squad including the likes of Sergio Aguero, Yaya Toure, David Silva and Vincent Kompany.

Why did the writer use *the likes of*? Couldn't they just say "including Sergio..."?

Answer (score 1):

In this context the author wants to highlight the calibre of Manchester City squad by mentioning some important players.

Using the expression "a squad including the likes of" shows the interest in stressing the effort assembling a team with renowned players: "a squad with players of the highest level such as" or "a squad with players as good as".

Comment: He could equally well have said 'such as', or 'players like....'

Comment: No. @appfreak is correct. To say *the likes of* implies more strongly that these were *of the same calibre as*.